# X.509 certificate translation to SecCertificateRef

Tags: ssl, x509

I am connecting to server using openSSL.

After I get the certificate/chain in X509 format, I want to use Apple's security framework to validate the certificate(s).

In order to do that I would need to translate the **X.509 structure** to SecCertificateRef.

Below fails..

```
X509 *x509cert = ..;
SecCertificateRef certificateRef = SecCertificateCreateWithData(NULL, X509Cert);
```

`SecCertificateCreateWithData` expects data in CFDataRef (DER encoded X.509 certificate) format.

Does anybody have any sample code for this?

Answer (score 1):

what is the file extension of your certificate?
You probably have to convert it to a DER format

```
openssl x509 -outform der -in certificate.pem -out certificate.der
```

Answer (score 0):

```
X509 *x = ...
BIO *x_bio = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
i2d_X509_bio(x_bio, x);
BIO_flush(x_bio);
char *x509Pointer;
long x509Length = BIO_get_mem_data(x_bio, &x509Pointer);
NSData *certData = [NSData dataWithBytes:x509Pointer length:x509Length];
SecCertificateRef cert = SecCertificateCreateWithData(NULL, (__bridge CFDataRef)certData);
BIO_free_all(x_bio);
```